# How to create custom variable (%%title%%) for meta field in wordpress for yoast seo plugin

Tags: wordpress, seo

I want to create %%title%% variables for meta field which I want to use in yoast seo settings.

Please guide me how can I do this

Comment: Looks like you'll need something like `%%cf_<custom-field-name>%%`. I would suggest reading through [Yoast SEO: Titles & Metas template variables](https://kb.yoast.com/kb/yoast-wordpress-seo-titles-metas-template-variables/)

Comment: @Frits That has worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can target a custom meta field by using `%%cf_<custom-field-name>%%` in your *SEO Title* field.

Here's a reference of all the available variables on Yoast:

[Yoast SEO: Titles & Metas template variables](https://kb.yoast.com/kb/yoast-wordpress-seo-titles-metas-template-variables/)

Here's an example of what it should look like:

[image: SEO Title with Custom Meta Field]